# I want to create a bookmark to a div, and i want the bookmark to be contained within a list

Tags: html, css

I want to have a bookmark that leads to a div. The bookmark needs to be in a list. Whenever i click on the bookmark it just always goes to the first div and not the one i have indicated.

```
<div id="bookmarks">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="example1"</li>
        <li><a href="example2"</li>
    </ol>

</div>

<div id="example1">
    <img id="img1" src="exampleimg.jpg">
    <h3 id="exapmletext">Example</h3>
</div>



<div id="example2">
    <h3>example</h3>
</div>
```

It should go to the div I have provided the id of, but it always goes to the first div

Comment: Anchors need the # sign and your links are broken: `<a href="#example1">Link</a>`. Also if the page isn't tall enough, the lower divs won't be scrolled to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your a tag is not being closed properly.
2. To define an anchor link in an a tags href attribute you need to prepend the id string with #.

```css
html,body {
 height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookmarks">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#example1">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#example2">Example 2</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div id="example1">
    <img id="img1" src="https://placebear.com/640/360">
    <h3 id="exapmletext">Example</h3>
</div>

<div id="example2">
    <h3>example</h3>
</div>
```